# Ionic background geolocation issue

Tags: background, ionic2, geolocation, tracker

I am working on Ionic background Geolocation App. I am facing an issue, when I close the app from the background, then background geolocation service not work. I want that if the app is removed from the background, the app background geolocation service should work.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

You can install background geolocation plugin

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation

Answer (score 1):

You can install background geolocation plugin

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

and also add this in .ts for example,

```
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';

constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation) { }

...

const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 30,
            debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
            stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
    };

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

    console.log(location);

    // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
    // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
    // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
    this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

  });

// start recording location
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

// If you wish to turn OFF background-tracking, call the #stop method.
this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
```

for further reference kindly refer this link

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/

Comment: If i remove the app from background.?kindly help me

Comment: already tried but got error "Plugin not installed error" in the console?